# Grammar rules for ending a sentence with "is had"

Tags: grammar

I am searching for documentation that explains whether or not the specific grammar used in the following sentences is technically correct.

1)  "Lunch is had."

2)  "We are not going to go to the swimming pool until lunch is had."

Any explanations and corresponding references would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The past tense of _have_ is _had_.

Comment: For #1, a more common phrasing might be either "Lunch is served" or "Lunch is ready."   I honestly do not know whether or not either sentence is grammatical, but neither makes me cringe to hear.  Good question.

Comment: @cobaltduck 'Lunch is taken' is synonymous; the other two suggestions are not.

Comment: "We are not going to go to the swimming pool until lunch is had / taken." means that you're waiting until _others_ start their lunch. Do you mean "We are not going to go to the swimming pool until lunch has been taken." ? ('Taken' is far more idiomatic than 'had' here.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Another way to express the thought I had in mind would be this, "We are not going to go to the swimming pool until lunch has been eaten/taken."  That said, I'm specifically curious about the grammar in my original sentence, even though using "is had" is not common vernacular.

Comment: The answer to the question is that _have_ with a meal or food name is a fixed form idiom for _eat_: _They had breakfast/bacon/grapefruit/supper/a picnic_. These idioms don't passivize; idioms are, after all, irregular. Thus *_Breakfast/Bacon/Grapefruit/Supper/A picnic was had by them_ can't work.

Comment: "Is had", in that context, is not perfectly grammatical (and certainly not formal), but it a sort of humorous slang -- an intentional grammatical error.

Comment: Similar use of *had* I found in NYT years back is *a movie to be had* or something similar.

Comment: Of course, if someone took unfair advantage of lunch in order to defraud it, you could say, "Lunch has been had."

Answer (score 1):

As the commentariat has pointed out, *to have a meal* is idiomatic for eating a meal, and it is rarely transposed to the passive, i.e., you almost always read or hear "I had lunch" instead of "lunch was had by me." But the latter usage is easily understood, and *almost* always isn't a universal. Charles Dickens used the phrasing in *Our Mutual Friend* --

> Then, **dinner is had** at the Hotel with the legal gentleman, and
>   then there are in due succession, nomination, and declaration.

In a (shall we say) more mundane publication, the [*Kansas City Bar Bulletin*](https://books.google.com/books?id=UmU8AAAAIAAJ&q=%22dinner%20is%20had%22&dq=%22dinner%20is%20had%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin-qLFsrLOAhXLOSYKHaeUAC4Q6AEIMDAE) (Vol 23, 1949) is found

> ... the Bar Directory is self-sustaining in that the advertisements
>   bring in about $1,200.00. which is the approximate cost of the
>   publication. Each meeting we hold, costs the Association considerable,
>   depending on whether or not a **dinner is had**.

Here the treasurer has used the passive to give proper emphasis to the subject, dinner, as the determiner of expenditure.